# I cannot create a model using `isar` and `freezed`

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed, flutter-isar

I want to create a model like the following, but the `.g.` file for `isar` is not being generated.

```dart
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';

part 'model.freezed.dart';
part 'model.g.dart';

@freezed
@Collection(ignore: {'copyWith'})
class Model with _$Model {
  const factory Model({
    required Id id,
    required String name,
  }) = _Model;
  const Model._();
}
```

error:

```
Target of URI hasn't been generated: 'package:my_app/entity/model.g.dart'.
Try running the generator that will generate the file referenced by the URI.
```

How can I make `freezed` and `isar` coexist and generate files together?

Comment: Have you run the command `dart run build_runner build` in the same directory as your `pubspec.yaml` file?

Comment: I ran it in the same directory as the pubspec.yaml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pubspec.yaml file, use latest isar and freezed package,

```dart
isar: ^4.0.0-dev.14
isar_flutter_libs: ^4.0.0-dev.14
freezed_annotation: ^2.4.1
```

In your model.dart class, change `Id id  int id`

```dart
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';

part 'model.freezed.dart';
part 'model.g.dart';

@freezed
@Collection(ignore: {'copyWith'})
class Model with _$Model {
  const factory Model({
    // required Id id, //Don't use this❌
    required int id,   //Use this ✅
    required String name,
  }) = _Model;
  const Model._();
}
```

Then run this command in your terminal

```
dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

This will generate both model.freezed.dart, model.g.dart file together.

For breaking in ISAR v4, read it [isar 4.0.0-dev.14 changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/isar/versions/4.0.0-dev.14/changelog).

Comment: Thnks!!!!!!!!!!